# Изменение расположения внутренних элементов Toolbar (navigation indicator и overflow icon)

Tags: android, android-toolbar

**Дано:**

`Toolbar` нестандартной высоты. **Navigation indicator** и **overflow icon** в нём располагаются посередине по высоте. (см. скриншоты).

**Задача:**

Переместить **Navigation indicator** и **overflow icon** вверх так, как если бы `Toolbar` был стандартной высоты.

**Возможное решение:**

Узнать **id** `View`, содержащих иконки, и изменить их **LayoutParams**. Похоже (судя по второму скриншоту), что изменения **gravity** на **top** должно хватить.

**Попытка решения:**

Пробовал получить дочерние `View` `Toolbar`-а, но метод `getChildCount()` экземпляра `Toolbar`-а возвращает **0**.

**Вопрос:**

Как и где узнать **id** `View`, содержащих иконки `Toolbar`-а?

**Скриншоты:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитал [документацию](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). Там пишут:

1. > The navigation button is vertically aligned within the Toolbar's minimum height, if set
2. > Action buttons are vertically aligned within the Toolbar's minimum height, if set.

Таким образом, проставив `android:minHeight` `Toolbar`-у:

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

желаемое отображение было достигнуто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Мораль:**

*RTFM!*